# Can I run this C code in Visual Studio?

Tags: c, visual-studio

Can I run this code in Visual Studio ? I know there is Linux/Unix libraries, but how can convert the code for Visual Studio ?

All of the code is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxYN1HoaM7pJV1JVRmtnZzhqUEk/view?usp=sharing

```c
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/timeb.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define MAX_CLIENT_PER_THREAD 300
#define MAX_THREAD 200
#define PORT 3355
#define MAX_CLIENT_BUFFER 256

int listenfd;

typedef struct {
    pthread_t tid;
    int client_count;
    int clients[MAX_CLIENT_PER_THREAD];
}Thread;

pthread_cond_t new_connection_cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t new_connection_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

Thread threads[MAX_THREAD];

void nonblock(int sockfd) {
    int opts;
    opts = fcntl(sockfd, F_GETFL);
    if(opts < 0) {
        perror("fcntl(F_GETFL)\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    opts = (opts | O_NONBLOCK);
    if(fcntl(sockfd, F_SETFL, opts) < 0) {
        preror("fcntl(F_SETFL)\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}
...
```

Comment: I suggest you just compile it in Visual Studio and see what the compiler/linker tells you. Seems that most of your code is supported in VS.

Comment: Not likely. Anything  `pthread` will be a problem, as well as sockets.

Comment: If I just compile it, the compiler show me many errors, because of unsupported libraries.